# Combining conditional formatting search formula to only highlight results with a blank field

Tags: excel, search

I have this formula (which works) to highlight only those entries that match a string entered into a search box. I need to exclude those rows where column A has a value (starting at row A5) in any row. The current formula is this:

`=IF(ISBLANK(Search_box),0,SEARCH(Search_box,$B4))`

And it works well but highlights ALL rows where the search string is valid, whether or not there is anything in column A. I want to exclude those rows where there is a value in any row in column A.

Thank you in advance. Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Include another if statement that tests whether there is something in Column A (and print 0 otherwise). For example, it would be something like:

=IF(ISBLANK(Search_box),0,IF(NOT(ISBLANK($A4)),0,SEARCH(Search_box,$B4)))